# What are the differences between virtualizing a webapp and transforming it into a cloud-native application?

Tags: web-applications, cloud, virtualization, cloud-native

Could someone tell me what are the differences between virtualizing a webapp and transforming it into a cloud-native application?

Any shared information about this topic would be much appreciated.

Regards

YT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualizing a web application and transforming it into a cloud application represent two distinct approaches to application deployment.

Essentially, the key difference is that virtualizing a web application involves running the existing application within a virtual environment, while converting an application into a cloud application entails restructuring and redesigning the application to fully leverage the benefits of the cloud environment. This typically involves breaking down the application into microservices, each of which can be independently deployed, updated, and scaled.